# How to get preloaded .apk installed in the "stopped" state and *not* start on BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

We have an application that is being evaluated for preload on some devices.  Our application has a service that will run automatically on BOOT_COMPLETED as long as the application is not in the "stopped" state.  When an application is installed on a device the application is in the "stopped" state and will not run automatically until the user launches it.  At that time it is no longer in the "stopped" state and will run automatically on BOOT_COMPLETED.  If the user force stops the app it will go back into the "stopped" state.  This is all good and expected behavior.

Now, when our app is preloaded on a device it is not in the "stopped" state, therefore it runs without any user interaction when the device is started for the first time.  We do not want this to happen, we want the application to be preloaded in the "stopped" state.

So, my two questions are:

1) Can an application be preloaded in the "stopped" state, and if so how?  Or at least what can I tell the preload team to do because they are telling me they can not do it.

2) If an app can not be preloaded in the "stopped" state is there anything I can do when I get the BOOT_COMPLETED to tell if the user launched the app or not.  That way I can track that the user launched the app at least once and if not kill the app from running on BOOT_COMPLETED.  This is a hack I would like to avoid, so any other options would be appreciated as well.

Thanks!